# Tkinter reshaping canvas doesnt work object oriented

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-layout

Im still new to Tkinter and I was trying to make a login screen. The functionality is there, however I want my canvas to be 200x300px, however that doesnt seem to work. It returns me with a canvas to just about fit the button and input field. Please help!

```
import tkinter as tk

class Login_Screen:
def __init__(self, master):
    self.master = master
    self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.master, width=200, height=300)
    self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas)
    self.input_user_log = tk.Entry(self.frame)
    self.button1 = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Log in", width=15, command=self.return_login_info)
    self.input_user_log.pack()
    self.canvas.pack()
    self.button1.pack()
    self.frame.pack()

def return_login_info(self):
    print(self.input_user_log.get())


root = tk.Tk()
app = Login_Screen(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why are you putting a frame inside a canvas? For that matter, why are you using a canvas?

Comment: Well, I saw putting a canvas into root in many other threads and on a yt video. I put the frame inside my canvas because I want to use that main page for other things as well, and I thought that that would be a great way to partition them. What do you think I should do?

Comment: Actually you should use `self.canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=self.frame, anchor='nw')` instead of `self.frame.pack()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `geometry()` method on `master`.

```py
import tkinter as tk

class Login_Screen:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry("300x200")
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.master)
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas)
        self.input_user_log = tk.Entry(self.frame)
        self.button1 = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Log in", width=15, command=self.return_login_info)
        self.input_user_log.pack()
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.button1.pack()
        self.frame.pack()
```